# How to use textwrap on the new line character python

Tags: python-3.x, word-wrap

So I have a program that uses textwrap to edit a block of text, I used te `subsequent_indent` command to to a line space after every line but the problem is, it doesn't affect blank lines. For example, if i have some text as so:

```
bloom, broom, soap, purple

carrot, turkey, abacus
```

it should add a line space after everyline to give:

```
bloom, broom, soap, purple


carrot, turkey, abacus
```

Which would then have 3 blank spaces in between each line but instead I get this

```
bloom, broom, soap, purple
carrot, turkey, abacus
.
```

ignore the "."

Is there anyway to fix this?

Also, I used the `initial_indent` to get it to work for the first line

okay, this is the code I used.

```
 para="\n".join(textwrap.wrap(para, LW, break_long_words=False, break_on_hyphens=False, initial_indent=("\n"*LS), subsequent_indent=("\n"*LS)))
```

para stands for each paragraph, it eits the text paragraph by paragraph

LW is the line width

LS is the line space value

it works fine adding a line space in between lines within the paragraph but my problem is adding line spacing between paragraphs

Comment: Hi Drew, would be easier to help if you provided a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just did thank you